# Cracking open results returned by Ember peekAll

Tags: ember.js

I'm playing around with peekAll(), trying to understand how it works for the ultimate purpose of iterating through the results.

In a route's model hook, I have:

```
var peekAllResults = this.store.peekAll('position');
console.log("peekAllResults = ", peekAllResults);
var peekAllResultsContent = peekAllResults.get('content');
console.log("peekAlLresultsContent = ", peekAllResultsContent);
```

This is returning data, as expected based on what I've got in my app.

In particular, here's what shows in the console:

[image]

So far so good. There are 8 records as expected based on what I've got going on.

But when when I add:

```
console.log("peekAllResultsContent.length=", peekAllResultsContent.length)
```

I get: peekAllResultsContent.length = 0

Same thing if I do peekAllResultsContent.get("length")

What is going on there?

I thought peekAll was a synchronous call that returned an array. Is there some trick to cracking it open and seeing what's actually in the array? I can't even get the length, so I figure I'm not on the right track.

Comment: You should not do `.get('content')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is wrapped into `Ember.Model` objects so you won't see clear results from `console.log`.
But there is no magic behind it. If the entities are already loaded into store you can get them via `peekAll`.

```
const positions = this.get('store').peekAll('position');
console.log('positions length', positions.get('length');

//we can iterate over them:
positions.forEach(position => {
  console.log(position.get('name'));
};

//we can filter them:
const southOnlyPositions = positions.filter(position => position.get('direction') === 'south');
```

and so on...

Btw: even for promises you are not supposed to access content. You get the result like this:

```
const promises = this.get('store').findAll('position');

promises.then(positions => {
  // positions here behave same as before
});
```