# Ember: How can I tell if peekAll returns any models?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have an external API that I wish to call ONLY if I do not already have a model for the data that comes back.

I'm trying to do something like this in my route:

```
let positions = this.store.peekAll('position');
if (positions.content.length < 1) {
    //make API call to fetch new data
}
```

But I'm learning the hard way that one can't call `length` on `.content`. :/ What's the best way to get around this? I tried just looking at the variable `positions`, but that object is returned whether there is data or not.

PS. I can't use some of ember's built in caching methods here because I'm querying rather than using findRecord or findAll.

Comment: I'm confused with this `positions.content` as positions should be array. What is content - position relationship?

Comment: `Positions` is a model class that is returned by peekAll. `content` is the property that Ember uses by convention to house a sub-property, `__data`, which contains my records. Here is a useful screenshot from someone also struggling: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40053053/cracking-open-results-returned-by-ember-peekall

Comment: try `positions.get('length')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nowadays the `content` sub-property should never be used, it's deprecated for public use for a couple of years now (because the `content` prop returns an array with InternalModels).

You got two options:

1. Get the native array: `positions.getArray().length`
2. Get the length by it's computed property: `positions.get('length')`